# Can I inject css in InfoPath form?

Tags: office-365, infopath

We are using SharePoint Online in O365 with some InfoPath forms. These are contenttype based InfoPath forms. There are some fields of type "single line of text". We make these fields multiple line in InfoPath (not in SharePoint) and it is  not wrapping in chrome. I would like to fix it with some css. Can I inject css in the InfoPath forms?

**This is the issue:**

[image]

**This is the expected situation:**

[image]

Comment: You should be able to target the elements in an InfoPath as usual HTML but the ID's are horrible.

Comment: But where I can inject css? In the infopath form or somewhere in the SharePoint site? For example in an custom action.

Answer (score 0):

InfoPath itself does not support CSS. It's possible you could do something on the page where it's being rendered, but there are no settings, properties, etc., in infopath to configure css styles or a link to a css file.